# Rider Language level keeps resetting

Tags: unity, c#

We've started working with Unity 2018.3.0b11 recently, and this means we can now use newer C# features, which is amazing! However, every time I've restarted Rider, it starts complaining about any C# 7.0 features, like this:

[image: Resharper complaining about C# 7.0 features]

The autofix is to allow ReSharper to suggest C# 7.0 features:

[image: Resharper C# 7.0 auto fix]

Opening the properties for the assembly will show that the language level has been set back to "latest":

[image: Language back to "latest"]

If I change it to 7.3 specifically and close and re-open the settings, it now explains that the settings are overridden in the "Rider Settings" to C# 6.0.

[image: Language is overridden in Rider Settings to C# 6.0]

If I click "Reset" it will then work, until the next time I restart Rider and it will be back to the first state above.

Using the "auto-fix" seems to take step one first (change to 7.0 specifically), still complaining though, and then if I do it a second time, it will do the second step ("Reset").

Is anyone else experiencing this with Unity 2018, and have you worked out a permanent fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it will be fixed in Rider 2018.3:

https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/issues/956

So, it's just a matter of waiting for it to be released, or using nightly builds until then...

Comment: Im having this same issue whit Rider 2019.3